# Function to create a view not working in postgresql - ERROR: column does not exist

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, stored-procedures, view

I am trying to make function that creates a simple view from a stored function.

Below is the query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cc_getbalancesfordate_vw(thedate date)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$


CREATE VIEW cc_showbalances_vw AS 
select * from cc_getbalancesfordate(thedate::date);


   $BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql
```

If I execute the above query in pgadmin sql window it works. But if I run a query like below

```
select cc_getbalancesfordate_vw('2014-02-15');
```

to test the function then I am getting the following error

```
ERROR:  column "thedate" does not exist
LINE 5: select * from cc_getbalancesfordate_vw(thedate::date);
```

thedate is not a column. I am looking the date pass to the function as a parameter.

I have also tried the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cc_getbalancesfordate_vw(thedate date)
   RETURNS void AS
$BODY$


Begin           

CREATE VIEW cc_showbalances_vw AS 
SELECT * FROM cc_getbalancesfordate(thedate);

end;   
   $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I got the same error. I have looked all over and cant find an example which does this. the examples I found is all to run a static query from a table. Not get an single example using a function parameter.

sorry there were mistakes. But the fact remains the same, it still does not work. I need to call this function which will make a view from another function. The naming is irrelevant at this point. Something is wrong in the syntax.

any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Jason

Comment: I am confused what you are trying to do. create a function which creates a view, which selects itself but returns nothing... I think you have got the name of your view and your function mixed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have looked all over and cant find an example which does this. the examples I found is all to run a static query from a table. Not get an single example using a function parameter.

Because a View IS a "static query from a table (or tables)" 
 - and they do not accept parameters

What you are attempting, to use a function to create a view is just wrong.

Your use of naming conventions are odd also. The NAME cc_getbalancesfordate_vw belongs to a VIEW (_vw)

Comment: it is not my naming convention just what I have to follow. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: yes, but your adherence to the naming convention is wrong. a function probably has a `_fn` suffix, so if creating a function that name of that function cannot end with `_vw`